# how to move one or more value from one listbox to another using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

this code runs but I should select one item. I want to know how pass the value without selection

Comment: If you do not select then how do you know which value is going to be moved?

Comment: Without selection, How do you determine which are all the values that you wanted to move?

Comment: `listbox.items[index]` for a know item, can work without selection.

Comment: i want to pass all values from one listbox to another listbox

Comment: for example we have 10 names i want to move all from one textbox to another textbox

Comment: "want to move all" is very different from the "move one or more" in the title. And it's the crucial part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a selected item but only the index you can use [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx), if you want to add it to the other list you need the object anyway so you can use the [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
object item = listBox1.Items[index];
listBox2.Items.Add(item);
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
```

If you want to add all items use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);
}
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: @bakhshi: what does it do instead?

Comment: but i want to pass all values

Comment: How to display all values of text box in label
 
  
i can display one item when i select it 
but i can't display all items at once

What I have tried:

i tried this 
form1 
private void btn_voit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string textboxchoix = listBox2.Text; 
Form2 frm = new Form2(textboxchoix);
frm.Show();
}
form2 
public Form2(string textboxchoix)
{
InitializeComponent();
label_choix.Text = textboxchoix;

Comment: You can separate all strings  with a delimiter, for example semicolon: `String.Join(";", listBox1.Items.Cast<string>())` (if the objects are really strings, otherwise use `ToString`)

Comment: it dont work i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
var i = 0;// let i as the index which you want it to be moved.
var targetItem = listBox1.Items[i];
listBox2.Items.Add(targetItem);
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

Comment: `listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);` it should be like this.

Comment: ha ha, thanks for the fixing.